# Are there any alternative to cursor in Oracle for performance improvements?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I have the below query which truncates specific tables in a specific schema. Is there a better option to do this without cursor? This query takes a a few minutes to execute as the schema is big.

```
DECLARE TYPE cur_typ IS REF CURSOR;
c           cur_typ;
qry_str   VARCHAR2(1000);
table_name    VARCHAR2(50);    
BEGIN
qry_str := \'SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_ALL_TABLES
    WHERE (TABLE_NAME like \'\'STG_%\'\'
      OR TABLE_NAME like \'\'S_%\'\' )\';

OPEN c FOR qry_str;
LOOP
    FETCH c INTO table_name;
    EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE \'TRUNCATE TABLE \' || table_name; 
END LOOP;
CLOSE c;
```

Do any of you have any faster alternative?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: drop schema and recreate?

Comment: There is now need for dynamic select statement. Go for staic one

Answer (score 3):

If there is more than handful of tables, TRUNCATE is the bigger issue than the query. It's DDL, pretty heavy statement.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried an inline cursor?

```
 BEGIN
    FOR row in (
        SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_ALL_TABLES
         WHERE TABLE_NAME like 'STG_%'
            OR TABLE_NAME like 'S_%'
    ) LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || row.table_name; 
    END LOOP;
END;
```

That doesn't get rid of the cursor, just hides it under the covers, but is more readable.  If you are seeing performance problems, try tuning the query.

Comment: +1 Using this type of cursor is simpler and faster (because of automatic bulk collect), but I have a feeling the `SELECT` part of this process is not the bottleneck.  If this is really the entire query, it would be unusual for it to take more than a second.

Answer (score -2):

You can use  FORALL. 
You can also store tables you want to truncate in separate table and do not query dictionary table.